# Shortcut for "Network and Sharing Center"

Tags: windows-7, networking

Is there a control panel link to open the **Network and Sharing Center** in Windows 7 ?.

**Edit**: I am aware that the command: `control.exe /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter` does what I want, but I was hopeing for something like `appwiz.cpl` (used for opening **Add/Remove Programs**) as these are easier to remember and works everywhere.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

And I found the answer.
Try:

> control.exe /name Microsoft.NetworkandSharingCenter

Comment: is there any other option in Microsoft.* namespace??

Comment: This only works if user is granted permissions to Network and Sharing Center. My institution blocks this with global policies for standard users. Giovanni's method works, even when not given permissions.

Answer (score 9):

You can use ncpa.cpl command to open ( Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connections ) and start from there.

Comment: improve and i'll reverse my vote, im personally againts the 1 line answers.

Comment: this is the best answer, so you are wrong.

Comment: Can you share the source of this answer. this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Alternate method:

Press <kbd>[image] (Windows)</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Paste `explorer.exe shell:::{8E908FC9-BECC-40f6-915B-F4CA0E70D03D}` *or* the command previously provided above.

After testing, create a shortcut using *either* one of those commands and assign it a hotkey sequence... use said hotkey to launch in the future.  Check out `%SystemRoot%\System32\netcenter.dll` for viable shortcut icons...

While this, of course, doesn't fulfill your "use everywhere" requirement, you could create an installer batch script on a flash drive and bring that everywhere with you.

*Realistically*, the fastest method (for use with any Windows 7 system) might be to press <kbd>[image]</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, type "sharing", and, when "Network and Sharing Center" is highlighted,
press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This is also an Help Desk related question, I suppose, and therefore I vote for the "Realistically" part: well done.

Answer (score 3):

Network and Sharing Center

```
control /name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter
```

Network Connections

```
control ncpa.cpl
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just open Control Panel - All Control Panel Items, right click on the link for Network and Sharing Center, choose Create Shortcut, that'll put a shortcut on your desktop, you can rename the shortcut to whatever you like  - then move it to your system root folder and voila! open it from the Run command or copy to a flash drive for portability.

Answer (score -2):

This is how to add the Network & Sharing Center link and icon to RocketDock:-

1. Bring Up Control Panel.
2. Right-click on the Network & Sharing Center icon and then click on 'Create Shortcut'.
3. Go to your directory within the 'Users' folder on the C drive, i.e. if your name is Steve, go to 'Users\Steve'.
4. Create a new folder called 'Control Panel Links', i.e. 'Users\Steve\Control Panel Links'.
5. Cut the Network & Sharing Center shortcut icon that was created on the desktop in 2 above and paste it in 'Users\Steve\Control Panel Links'.  The shortcut will be called 'Network and Sharing Center - Shortcut' in 'Users\Steve\Control Panel Links'.
6. Rename 'Network and Sharing Center - Shortcut' as 'Network & Sharing Center'.
7. Add new icon to the RocketDock dock by right-clicking on the dock and left-clicking on 'Add Item' then 'Blank Icon'.  The new blank icon then appears as a question mark.
8. Move the question mark icon to where you want it to be.
9. Once you are satisfied that you have the question mark icon where you want it to be, right-click on the question mark icon and then left-click on 'Icon Settings ...'.
10. Put 'Network & Sharing Center' (without the quotes) in the 'Name' box.
11. In 'Target', put '%USERPROFILE%\Control Panel Links\Network & Sharing Center.lnk' (also without quotes).
12. To change the icon to the Network & Sharing Center icon, click on the '+' button.
13. Go to where the 'netcenter.dll' file will be stored, i.e. in 'C:\Windows\System32'.  (You can only add 'C:\Windows\System32', but not 'C:\Windows\System32\netcenter.dll' but don't worry!)
14. Go down the list of all DLL files that has been found.  Stop when you come to 'netcenter.dll'.
15. Click on 'netcenter.dll'.
16. Then click on any one of the N & SC icons (probably the '?14' one).
17. Then click on 'OK'.

The same method can also be used with Classic Shell, giving you 'This PC' (which you can also rename as 'Computer' if you like), 'Network Connections' and 'Network & Sharing Center'.

Comment: Please explain how the use of RocketDock or Classic Shell answers the question? OP is using neither of these programs. In addition Classic Shell already has a link to "Network & Sharing Center" in the start menu "Control Panel" under the customise options ...